# React custom Axios hook with processing state, causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm trying to create a custom `Axios` hook, with processing/loading state.
I mean the hook should return an `axios` instance and also a processing state, so that I can use that state to show some spinner or disable submit button etc.

I've used Axios interceptors for it, like this:

```js
const useAxios = ({
  baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
  withCredentials = true,
  headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
}) => {
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(false)

  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    headers: headers,
    withCredentials,
  });

  instance.interceptors.request.use(
    function (config) {
      setProcessing(true)
      return config;
    },
    function (error) {
      setProcessing(false)
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  instance.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
      setProcessing(false)
      return response;
    },
    function (error) {
      setProcessing(false)
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  return {
    axios: instance,
    processing,
  }
}
```

### The problem:

When I'm trying to use this hook inside some component's `useEffect` like this:

```js
  const { axios } = useAxios();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/api/some-endpoint')
  }, [axios])
```

It causes infinite loop,
I think the issue here is, as the `useAxios` has a state (processing) so, when-ever that state changes, the `useEffect` runs and that `useEffect` again calls the `API` which again causes the state to update, and we get the loop.

If I simply remove the `axios` from useEffect's dependecy array it works fine, But `eslint` is not happy with that, it gives this error:
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'axios'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. [eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920)
So, I guess that's not a good practice.

I'm not sure, what to do exactly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating the `axios` instance on render, the change triggers the `useEffect`, which makes an api call, that causes a re-render, that changes the `axios` instance...

Memoize the Axios instance using a ref and `useMemo`, and make sure that all dependencies won't change between renders (like the `defaultHeaders`), and memoize them as well:

```
const defaultHeaders = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json'
}

const useAxios = ({
  baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
  withCredentials = true,
  headers = defaultHeaders
}) => {
  const axiosRef = useRef()
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: baseURL,
      headers: headers,
      withCredentials,
    });

    instance.interceptors.request.use(
      function(config) {
        setProcessing(true)
        return config;
      },
      function(error) {
        setProcessing(false)
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    instance.interceptors.response.use(
      function(response) {
        setProcessing(false)
        return response;
      },
      function(error) {
        setProcessing(false)
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    axiosRef.current = instance;
  }, [baseURL, withCredentials, headers])

  return {
    axios: axiosRef.current,
    processing,
  }
}
```

Comment: I think using interceptors inside `useMemo` isn't entirely correct, because docs (https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo#parameters) say function which you pass to `useMemo` should be *pure*. What do you think?

Comment: Configuring interceptors of an axios instance is not a side effect of the `useMemo`. The memo gets parameters and produces a memoized instance.

Comment: No I meant whether using `instance.interceptors.request.use` inside `useMemo` would make *function passed* to `useMemo` impure (which violates docs). But since `instance` was created inside `useMemo` I am not sure anymore...

Comment: at least I would add warning about `useMemo` as from the docs: "You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.", which means it can rerun even if deps don't change

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava - yep, you're right. It's better to create and memoize the instance manually with `useRef` and `useEffect`.

Comment: Now, there is another problem, if child component uses `useAxios` inside its effect, the effect of parent won't have run yet :) which means interceptors won't be initialized

Comment: That's a standard react problem. If the instance needs to be available to both parent and children, you should use the `useAxios` in the parent. In this case, you'll probably want to create the instance outside of the hook, and just serve it via the hook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251143/discussion-between-giorgi-moniava-and-ori-drori).